Streamlit application multithreaded by default, but not synchronized
I am making a streamlit application, which is a chatbot, that should refer to a list of chat messages.
For this purpose, I have stored the those chat messages in a variable "messages" in the session variables, so that it is not lost when the page is rerun.
I have initialised the variable "messages" as follows:
if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.messages = []

This variable has been used many times later in the application, and on debugging i have realised that it works fine till a major part of the app, until it comes to a function that has to simply return that variable. Something like this:
def return_messages():
    return st.session_state.messages

This gives an error: streamlit.errors.NoSessionContext
As per this answer on the streamlit forum (not yet solved),

IMHO this happens because the agents are executed via a threadpool and the callbacks are just passed to the agents and these are trying to update the state of streamlit which is in another thread and which leads to an exception

Also, to debug, i have added random print statements at different locations in the code.
The expected execution flow should have printed:
*******************************************************************************
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
*******************************************************************************
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

But there are times when it shows:
*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
*******************************************************************************
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Immediately after printing that, it shows the following error:
2024-06-20 17:29:09.433 Thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-3_2': missing ScriptRunContext
2024-06-20 17:29:09.451 Thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-3_2': missing ScriptRunContext
2024-06-20 17:29:11.702 Uncaught app exception

Now my question is:

Is this because the execution of streamlit apps is multithreaded by default? Or am I misunderstanding something?
If it is multithreaded, how to synchronise it?
If it is not, then what could be the reason behind all this happening?

PS: I am not explicitly multithreading it.
